# React native and Firebase Authentication - handling expired token when auto logging in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In my application, I use firebase for authentication. Users can sign in using the **signInWithEmailAndPassword** method, which returns a token which I store in **AsyncStorage**. I want users to automatically login if a token is stored, else be sent to the login screen.

However due to firebase tokens expiring after an hour, this token would be invalid after that amount of time, therefore authenticating a user is not possible. How would I handle this scenario, and allow users to auto login after any amount of time with any token, expired or not.

Would I store a **refresh token** in Storage? I looked into implementing methods such as **onIdTokenChanged** or **onAuthStateChanged**, however these require **currentUser** which wouldn't be accessible if a user tries auto logging in with an expired token stored. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try **implementing** `onIdTokenChanged`? The SDKs auto-request a fresh the ID token a few minutes before the current one expires. If you can't get that to work, it's probably helpful if you [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the behavior/error you got.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I call **onIdTokenChanged**, do I need to pass or supply any objects or paramters such as a user object, because I am only storing the token in storage, nothing else. I can not access the current logged in user object, as the token has expired.